# Mule studio as a plugin in Eclipse 4.x?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When I download the Mule Studio, it seems it's based on Eclipse 3.8. 
Is it possible to run Mule Studio as a plugin in newer versions of Eclipse, like Eclipse 4.3?

Comment: do you have eclipse plugin link for the version of mule mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few features that won't work in eclipse 4.x (i.e. DataMapper).

As stated in the documentation currently the plugin only support eclipse 3.8

I would recommend to keep using eclipse 3.8 until MuleSoft releases a version compatible with newer versions of Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As mentioned Mule Studio is built on Eclipse IDE.

You can get Studio ad Eclipse Plugin. 
MuleStudio Update Site - http://studio.mulesoft.org/3.5/plugin

Refer to the link given below for more details.

[Studio in Eclipse](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Studio+in+Eclipse)

Comment: the linked page says: "The Mule Studio Eclipse plugin is accessible in the Java, Java EE, and STS distributions that use Eclipse 3.8.". I was asking about Eclipse 4.x

Comment: There are a few features that won't work in eclipse 4.x (i.e. DataMapper). I would recommend to keep using eclipse 3.8 until MuleSoft releases a version compatible with newer versions of Eclipse

Comment: @genjosanzo i see, - if you provide that as an anwser, i'll accept it